# Swift non Inclusive Range with Double Dot

Tags: swift

```
for i in 0..100 {
    println("\(i)")
}
```

I different types of errors depending on the location of the statements:

- Operator is not a know
- Use of unresolved identifier '..'
- Braced block of statements is an unused closure

Comment: Which version of xcode? Did you put the code in a swift file or in playground?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The half-closed range operator has been changed to '..<' since Xcode beta 3. See release doc here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=3

The error message will disappear if you do this:

```
for i in 0..<100 {
    println("\(i)")
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your updated question